# Writing a dictionary of new variables and value. Using this to define value

Tags: python, dictionary, variables

I have a large number of variables I wish to contain. I currently have them in the form:

```
dict = {a: 1, 
        b: 2, 
        c: 3}
```

This obviously doesn't run because the variables are undefined.

Is there anyway of using this format in a script to define the variables, while allowing an easy input structure for data.

Comment: I'm not following. What are you trying to achieve? Could you give a specific example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
dict = {"a": 5, 
        "b": 2, 
        "c": 3}

locals().update(dict)
```

this will create local variables as a=5, b=2 ...

Comment: This still produces a NameError. I was wondering of a way to both define the variable by the relative value in a dictionary. 

The dictionary would go:

dict =  {a: 1, 
            b: 2, 
            c: 3}

While also stating a = 1, b = 2, c=3. I'm not sure if it is possible. Was just looking for a potential solution

Comment: `dict` is a bad variable name since it shadows the builtin dict constructor.

Comment: yes, I used `dict` name to relate it to the variable name in question, this name will definitely cause a problem

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `**kwargs` of a function:

```
def dictbuilder(**kwargs):
    return kwargs
```

Demo:

```
>>> dictbuilder(a=1, b=2, c=3)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: @wjandrea: Looks like I was trying to re-invent an oval wheel... Thanks forthe head ip, but better to delete that stuff